# asymptotic expansion and derivation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

we consider the equation 
$$
-u''(x)+ q(\xi)=0,
$$
where $\xi=\dfrac{x}{\epsilon}$.
We get
$$
u(x)= \sum_{l+p=0}^k  \epsilon^{l+p} N_l^p(\xi) D^l v(x)
$$
where $N_l^p$ are $1-$ periodic functions, and $D^l= \dfrac{d^l}{dx^l}$.
We plug $u$ in the equation, then the autor find that 
$$
-D^2 u+q(\xi) u= -\sum_{l+p}^{k+1} \epsilon^{l+p-2} H_l^p D^l v(x)+ B^{\epsilon,k}_l
$$
where
$$
H_l^p= \dfrac{d^2 N_l^p}{d \xi^2}(\xi)+2 \dfrac{d N^p_{l-1}}{d \xi}(\xi) + N_{l-2}^p(\xi) - q(\xi) N_l^{p-2}(\xi)
$$
and $B_l^{\epsilon,k}$ is given by
$$
B_l^{\epsilon,k}= \epsilon^k \left\{  
-\sum_{p+l=k+2} (2 \dfrac{d N^p_{l-1}}{d\xi}(\xi)+ N^p_{l-2}(\xi)- q(\xi) N_l^{p-2}(\xi)) D^l v(x) 
-\sum_{p+l=k+3} \epsilon (N_{l-2}^p(\xi) q(\xi) N_l^{p-2}(\xi)) D^l v(x)
\right\}
$$

I try to find the same result, so first we have that

\begin{align}
-u''+q(\dfrac{x}{\epsilon})u &= -D^2\left(\sum_{l,p=0}^k \epsilon^{l+p} N_l^p(\xi) D^l v(x)\right) + q(\xi) \sum_{l+p=0}^k \epsilon^{l+p} N_l^p(\xi) D^l v(x)\\
&= -\sum_{l+p=0}^k \epsilon^{l+p} D^2\left(N_l^p(\xi) D^l v(x)\right) 
+ q(\xi)\sum_{l+p=0}^k \epsilon^{l+p} N_l^p(\xi) D^lv(x)      
\end{align}
and we have that 
$$
D^2\left(N_l^p(\xi) D^lv(x)\right)= \epsilon^{-2} D^2 N_l^p(\xi) D^l v(x)
+ 2 \epsilon^{-1}DN_l^p(\xi) D^{l+1} v + N_l^p(\xi) D^{l+2} v(x)
$$

But i don't understand and i don't find how we find the same result of the author. Thank's to the help.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context (including what publication all this is from) and explain all your notation, e.g., what $q$ and $v$ are?

Comment: $q$ and $v=v_{\epsilon}$ are smooth function, and

Comment: the publication is in http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0014350, section method please i don't undestand can you help me